# Need to check a sentence input by user for profane words

Tags: java

```
package javaapplication15;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication15 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your sentence: ");
        String message = keyboard.nextLine();

        String[] words = {" gray "," better "," formed "," eggs "," made "," cost ",
            " decide "," sequence "," crap "," have "," two "," six "};

        if(message.toLowerCase().contains(words))
            System.out.println("Sentence contains profanity");
        else
            System.out.println("Sentence does not contain profanity");
    }   
}
```

I need the code to check for only the word in the array. If the sentence has craps instead of crap than it should display no profanity. My issue is the `if` statement. I tried to use the array name words with contains but says something about charsequence.

Comment: Read this before implementing: https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem... and the *actual* error message, not "says something about", would be important.

Comment: That's not going to work for `eggs.`

Comment: It says String[] cannot be converted to charsequence

Comment: That's because an array of String is not a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop through your words array

```
    boolean isRude = false;
    for (String oneword : words) {
        if(message.toLowerCase().contains(oneword)) {
            isRude = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isRude)
        System.out.println("Sentence contains profanity");
     else
        System.out.println("Sentence does not contain profanity");
```

in this example I use a boolean to capture whether profanity exists or not, and then print it out after the loop.

Another way to do this would to be also split the sentence into words using String.split and then compare word-to-word.  This would mean that you do not need to space-pad the profane words.

Comment: Just curious, why in fried eggs sake is this downvoted?  It is valid code and it fixes the reported error.

Comment: That was an accident.

Comment: nice to know.  *better formed eggs*

Comment: I am new to this site. I didnt realize that I downvoted it. Nice use of my words.

Comment: I tried to undo it but it wont change because I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: Now i have hit a green check mark. I dont know what that means.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution will only work for a small subset of the possible input, due to the extra spaces on both sides of the checked words. You should first come up with a clever method that doesn't need that.

For a question like this, I would use a HashSet. First, we hash the profanity words, then we hash the parsed input sentence and check for collisions:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProfanityChecker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String[] profanityWords = {"gray","better","formed", "eggs","made",
            "cost","decide","sequence","crap","have","two","six"};

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputSentence = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(checkForProfanity(profanityWords, inputSentence))
            System.out.println("Yes");
        else
            System.out.println("No");
    }

    private static boolean checkForProfanity(String[] profanityWords, String inputSentence)
    {
        HashSet<String> profanityHash = new HashSet<>();

        for(String word : profanityWords)
            profanityHash.add(word);

        String[] words = inputSentence.split("\\s+");

        for(String word : words)
            if(!profanityHash.add(word))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

This way, it will also work faster (m+n vs m*n). In a real life scenario, you would have a dictionary of profanityWords (size-m, 200-300) and a good length article to scan for (size-n, let's say 10000). It is important to use a good algorithm.

There are still a good bit of improvement you can do, such as preprocessing the inputSentence to cleaning up the special characters (.,!?*), or processing the words without the use of split, so it can even cope with a larger spectrum of input, faster.

I hope it helps. I believe it is good to think about the details..

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (from the package name) that this is a learning exercise.

So, here are a couple of hints to get you started:

1. The split the input line into words.  Look at the `String.split` method ... in the javadocs.

   If you have the text split into words, it is easier to match them. (You don't need to do complicated stuff to distinguish between complete words and partial words; e.g. the "Scunthorpe" problem.)
2. The spaces before / after the words in your `words` array are not helpful.  Even if you don't split the text into words, consider what happens when the first word of your text is "Gray" ... without a space in front of it.